# Pycocotools precision and recall

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, pycocotools

In `pycocotools` in `cocoeval.py` sctipt there is `COCOeval` class and in this class there is `accumulate` function for calculating `Precision` and `Recall`. Does anyone know what is this `npig` variable? Is this `negative-positive` or?

Because I saw this formula for recall: `Recall = (True Positive)/(True Positive + False Negative)`

Can I just use this `precision` and recall `variable` inside dictionary `self.eval` to get precision and recall of my model which I'm testing, and plot a `precision-recall curve`?

And the variable `scores` is this F1 score?

Because I'm not very well understand this `T,R,K,A,M` what is happening with this.

How can I print `precision` and `recall` in terminal?

```
def accumulate(self, p = None):
            '''
            Accumulate per image evaluation results and store the result in self.eval
            :param p: input params for evaluation
            :return: None
            '''
            print('Accumulating evaluation results...')
            tic = time.time()
            if not self.evalImgs:
                print('Please run evaluate() first')
            # allows input customized parameters
            if p is None:
                p = self.params
            p.catIds = p.catIds if p.useCats == 1 else [-1]
            T           = len(p.iouThrs)
            R           = len(p.recThrs)
            K           = len(p.catIds) if p.useCats else 1
            A           = len(p.areaRng)
            M           = len(p.maxDets)
            precision   = -np.ones((T,R,K,A,M)) # -1 for the precision of absent categories
            recall      = -np.ones((T,K,A,M))
            scores      = -np.ones((T,R,K,A,M))
    
            # create dictionary for future indexing
            _pe = self._paramsEval
            catIds = _pe.catIds if _pe.useCats else [-1]
            setK = set(catIds)
            setA = set(map(tuple, _pe.areaRng))
            setM = set(_pe.maxDets)
            setI = set(_pe.imgIds)
            # get inds to evaluate
            k_list = [n for n, k in enumerate(p.catIds)  if k in setK]
            m_list = [m for n, m in enumerate(p.maxDets) if m in setM]
            a_list = [n for n, a in enumerate(map(lambda x: tuple(x), p.areaRng)) if a in setA]
            i_list = [n for n, i in enumerate(p.imgIds)  if i in setI]
            I0 = len(_pe.imgIds)
            A0 = len(_pe.areaRng)
            # retrieve E at each category, area range, and max number of detections
            for k, k0 in enumerate(k_list):
                Nk = k0*A0*I0
                for a, a0 in enumerate(a_list):
                    Na = a0*I0
                    for m, maxDet in enumerate(m_list):
                        E = [self.evalImgs[Nk + Na + i] for i in i_list]
                        E = [e for e in E if not e is None]
                        if len(E) == 0:
                            continue
                        dtScores = np.concatenate([e['dtScores'][0:maxDet] for e in E])
    
                        # different sorting method generates slightly different results.
                        # mergesort is used to be consistent as Matlab implementation.
                        inds = np.argsort(-dtScores, kind='mergesort')
                        dtScoresSorted = dtScores[inds]
    
                        dtm  = np.concatenate([e['dtMatches'][:,0:maxDet] for e in E], axis=1)[:,inds]
                        dtIg = np.concatenate([e['dtIgnore'][:,0:maxDet]  for e in E], axis=1)[:,inds]
                        gtIg = np.concatenate([e['gtIgnore'] for e in E])
                        npig = np.count_nonzero(gtIg==0 )
                        if npig == 0:
                            continue
                        tps = np.logical_and(               dtm,  np.logical_not(dtIg) )
                        fps = np.logical_and(np.logical_not(dtm), np.logical_not(dtIg) )
    
                        tp_sum = np.cumsum(tps, axis=1).astype(dtype=np.float)
                        fp_sum = np.cumsum(fps, axis=1).astype(dtype=np.float)
                        for t, (tp, fp) in enumerate(zip(tp_sum, fp_sum)):
                            tp = np.array(tp)
                            fp = np.array(fp)
                            nd = len(tp)
                            rc = tp / npig
                            pr = tp / (fp+tp+np.spacing(1))
                            q  = np.zeros((R,))
                            ss = np.zeros((R,))
    
                            if nd:
                                recall[t,k,a,m] = rc[-1]
                            else:
                                recall[t,k,a,m] = 0
    
                            # numpy is slow without cython optimization for accessing elements
                            # use python array gets significant speed improvement
                            pr = pr.tolist(); q = q.tolist()
    
                            for i in range(nd-1, 0, -1):
                                if pr[i] > pr[i-1]:
                                    pr[i-1] = pr[i]
    
                            inds = np.searchsorted(rc, p.recThrs, side='left')
                            try:
                                for ri, pi in enumerate(inds):
                                    q[ri] = pr[pi]
                                    ss[ri] = dtScoresSorted[pi]
                            except:
                                pass
                            precision[t,:,k,a,m] = np.array(q)
                            scores[t,:,k,a,m] = np.array(ss)
            self.eval = {
                'params': p,
                'counts': [T, R, K, A, M],
                'date': datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                'precision': precision,
                'recall':   recall,
                'scores': scores,
            }
            toc = time.time()
            print('DONE (t={:0.2f}s).'.format( toc-tic))
```